# unordered HTML list with unordered list inside. Wrapped next each other

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I get an unordered list by a cms that I want to style.
It works well, but only for the first `<li id="link-18">` element. My goal is it to style the `<ul>` blocks all the way trough, like the first one. See http://jsfiddle.net/UyrdS/3/ (the second and third link shows the toggled `<ul>` block not on top)

[image: goal]

If the second link (level 2 two) is clicked, the toggled new `<ul>` block shows beside the navigation, but not on top like the level 1 one links does it with his children element `<ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up. I'm a pretty worse inquirer :)
Thanks for the answers. Kudos to you all for spending your time. This fiddle is the closest to my question.

http://jsfiddle.net/UyrdS/6/

But it's not dynamic. It has a static width. That is still the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can change your css to generate a nice submenu

```
nav ul>li>ul {
  display: none;
  margin-left:2em;
}
```

See the example on http://jsfiddle.net/WrcMX/

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/UyrdS/5/) is what you wanted

```
alllinks = $("ul>li>ul");
$('nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    alllinks.hide(); //First hide all the links
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).parent().children('ul').size() > 0) {
        $(this).parent().children('ul').toggle();
    }
});
```